# What is the eclipse global ecore resource set

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-emf, eclipse-emf-ecore

I would like to conceptually understand how Eclipse keeps track of its current resources in its environment, specifically (.ecore) files.

For example, when I right-click on an ecore file and click "Load Resources" and then click the button "Browse registered packages" (see the picture below), how eclipse populates this list.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access this information programmatically, have a look at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.EPackage.Registry.INSTANCE, it contains the global EPackage registry used by EMF.

This list is populated by the extensions declared in the file plugin.xml of the Eclipse plugin with a model generated by EMF (create a genmodel for your ecore and generate the model part of the code by right-clicking on the root of the genmodel). [Here](https://github.com/dartdesigner/Dart-Designer/blob/master/bundles/org.obeonetwork.dsl.dart/plugin.xml) is an example of the result for a Dart metamodel.

Comment: There are some parts I fail to follow: 1) in the phrasing "in the file plugin.xml of the Eclipse plugin with a model generated by EMF",  What is meant by "the Eclipse Plugin"?   2) How this registration mechanism happens by defining a new plugin and  is there any way to make an ecore package appear in this list without defining a new plugin ?

Comment: The registered packages are the EMF metamodels that have been registered inside of your instance of Eclipse by Eclipse plugins. If you want to contribute a new package to this list, you need to install the plugin containing your metamodel in your Eclipse.